# how do i implement shadow effect on the edge of a view in android?

Tags: android

After searching I only found how to set shadow&light effect to texts,how do I put shadow effect on a view, to make the edge between views more clear?

I know that you can set the background image with shadow effect to the view. But this does not really solve the problem unless I learn how to generate those images first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also place dummy `View` element at edges in layout. Set its background to a drawable xml with a gradient going black to transparent.

Answer (score 1):

```
paint.setShadowLayer(float radius, float dx, float dy, int color);
```

I guess this will be useful.